# Missing object properties in design metadata SQLite file

Tags: autodesk-forge

My model in Autodesk construction cloud contains several properties which I need to track. I have downloaded the sqlite file using [fetch derivative download URL](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeUrn-signedcookies-GET/) without any errors.

However when comparing export with what I see in ACC, or the [Fetch all properties call](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/), some properties are entirely missing. For instance, the [fetch all properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) call returns the 20 expected property values whereas only 3 of these values exist in the SQLite download. Any explanation why the SQLite file may be incomplete? There doesn't seem to any size restriction or filter in the call returning SQLite which may explain partial results.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that the design metadata returned via sqlite and via JSON may not be the same. For example, the metadata captured in the sqlite database use "instancing" where multiple design elements may inherit certain properties from another element (and the resolution of the inherited properties is left to whomever is reading this file). The JSON format on the other hand does not support any kind of inheritance, so properties are duplicated for each individual design element.